# Can I re-apply for a new PhD position of a better university if I am currently full funded international student of another university(both in US)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, transfer-student

Can I apply for a new PhD position of a better university(Stanford, Berkeley) in coming fall semester if I am currently international full funded PhD student of another university (both in US)? After acceptance I will leave the previous university.

Comment: Yes.  Not much to say.

Comment: of course you can, but is it advisible? that depends

Comment: If you leave one supervisor to go to another, will the new supervisor expect you to dump them as well? what happens to trust?

Comment: @SolarMike Students should not be "loyal" to supervisors.  They should act in their own interests.  The new supervisor should be offering a good deal to keep the student.  Students rarely find that supervisors are loyal to students.

Answer (score -2):

Yes: You can **drop-out, give-up funding, and start-over** with a new supervisor.

Albeit, that's **probably ill-advised** given the current climate.

Comment: Is it a law to give-up funding?

Comment: Not directly, but surely contractually: Why would your current university fund you to study at another? Something else to consider is whether your visa (if applicable) is tied to your current university: If you leave, does that invalidate your visa?

Comment: This is partly wrong.  PhD students who transfer in the US normally do not start over from the beginning.  If the funding is external it will not need to be given up.

Comment: _do not start over from the beginning_: True, credits for taught courses may be transferable. I merely meant start over with another supervisor. I'll edit. _If the funding is external it will not need to be given up_: That really depends on the funding structure. Generally, I'd assume funding is tied to a university.

Comment: @user2768 In the US, a visa gives you the right to ask for permission to enter the country.  It is neither needed nor sufficient to stay in the country. Transferring to a different PhD program will probably invalidate the visa for the next entry (in case it is a multiple-entry visa), but it will not prevent you from changing the PhD program.

Comment: @user151413 My understanding is that it's typically not a problem to enter the US on an unexpired F-1 visa with the old university's name on it. In any case, it's something to verify with the International Office while going through the SEVIS transfer process. If admitted on a J-1 visa there are more restrictions.

Comment: @Anyon Fair points, but in either case it does not matter directly whether the change of institutions invalidates the visa: If the visa under which one was admitted to the US allows change of programs, everything is fine, otherwise, well, not. But whether this invalidates the visa (i.e. it cannot be used for future entries to the country) is potentially a different question.  (It is completely legal to be in the US on an expired visa; citizens of some countries even get single-entry visas which expire after just a few months, yet then can legally stay as long as they have a valid contract.)